# Chrome does not react on Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm making a Javascript program which is supposed to make one element invisible when it's clicked and make another one visible.
It works perfectly in IE ( about what I really wonder, as Javascript rarely works there properly ), but in Chrome it doesn't react at all. Even when I'm just trying to make ordinary alert, it just doesn't display when I place it below the hideDisplay() function in code.

Here is the code:

Clicking on the image will make it invisible and display div background2 instead.
In IE it works, in Chrome it just 'selects' image - makes it with blue overlay.

```
<img src="screenxp.jpg" id="background1" onclick="hideDisplay(); window.setTimeout(failedto,1500);">
```

```
    // Getting the elements
var background1 = document.getElementById('background1');
var background2 = document.getElementById('background2');
var win = document.getElementById('win');

  // This is the function triggered when background1 ( image ) is clicked
function hideDisplay() {

    background1.style.display = 'none';
    background2.style.display = 'block';
    window.setTimeout(dispwin,2000);
}
```

Note: The background1 image is 100% width and height and absolute position, I don't know, it probably doesn't matter in JS code, but just noticing if it could be the reason of problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/B57DH/

Comment: Also, consider not using `onclick="hideDisplay()"`, but assign handlers from JavaScript (`background1.onclick = hideDisplay`, at its most primitive; there are other ways). Your problem was most likely scoping error (did you take a look at the JavaScript console? I bet you'll see something like `hideDisplay not defined`).

Comment: I opened Javascript console, hideDisplay is defined. But it just selects the image ( you know like when you click on desktop to select some file ) instead of executing Javascript code.

Comment: Where is th rest of the code - show the complete code

Comment: I opened Javascript console, hideDisplay is defined. But it just selects the image ( you know like when you click on desktop to select some file ) instead of executing Javascript code.

Amadan: Thanks, assigning handler works, but now another error came out: it doesn't wait for clicking, but immediately executed hideDisplay function when I assign it like this - hideDisplay(). Without () it doesn't work, too.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post a full code, because 'My post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.'. I just have to find out how to format it properly. ;)